# Firebase DB rules simulator allow read and write by unauthenticated users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-console

The simulator allows read/write to Posts key, but the results are correct for the Users key rules. Each post under Posts has a uid value representing a user in Users key.

Are my rules wrong or is the simulator wrong? Be gentle, I'm new to Firebase. :)

[image: Screenshot]

Two equals:

[image: Screen]

Redacted Data view: https: // i.stack.imgur.com/GaYMj.png (remove spaces around "//")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your rules to check that a `uid` child exists. For example:

```
".read": "data.child('uid').exists() && data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid"
```

Based on a quick test, I think what is occuring is that when a `uid` child does not exist, the evaluation of `data.child('uid').val()` fails and is handled by assigning it a value of false.  Similarly, because the user is not authenticated, `auth` is null and `auth.uid` also evaluates to false.  So your rule effectively becomes `".read": "false === false"`, which is true.

When I first simulated a read using your rule and I did not have a `uid` child in my database under `/posts/1`, the read was granted, as you reported.  When I added a `uid` child, it was not granted.

Comment: uid always exists for each post key. see my redacted data view screen shot. i will try your example though and report back.

Comment: That worked. But is that because it is not running against the actual data present or is that really the true fix for my data (see redacted data screen)?

Comment: The simulator uses the actual data in your database.  The screen shot only show data for key `-     CZWF`.  I don't know what's under key `1`, which is what you used in your example.

Comment: hmm ok. Did not know the simulator actually runs against the DB data. I'll have to do more testing with actual data. I assumed that having unauthenticated switched off would lock those visitors out completely. Maybe safer to have null checks for that before checking data.uid = auth.uid?